# All records returned when expanding JSON with IN clause

Tags: postgresql

I'm using JSON to pass in a list of ID's, however the following query always returns all records.

```
select first_name
from app.users
where id in (
    select id::varchar::bigint
    from json_array_elements('[9497902]'::json) id
);
```

Swapping out the JSON with the ID's manually brings back the expected amount of records:

```
select first_name
from app.users
where id in (
    9497902
);
```

Is there something I am missing to be able to work with JSON ID's?

Comment: Switching the alias for the json_array_elements to something like `user_id` seems to fix the problem, I think it conflicts with the `id` from the parent query, can anyone elaborate on what's happening there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ffd0b1d319d5ad92b2f8cb0f376ee4f8)

```
select name
from users
where id in (
    select id.value::varchar::bigint
    from json_array_elements('[1,3]'::json) id
);
```

The name `id` used within the subquery has been transferred from the outer query into the inner query. This can be checked just by executing this query:

```
select name
from users
where id in (
    select id
);
```

The alias of your JSON function is `id` but this is the name of the result set not of the column. The default column name of this function is `value`. So correctly you have to use `SELECT id.value...` or simply `SELECT value` to referrence the correct value.

Comment: I have now tested the answer and this did work, although I did find it easier to just rename my alias to avoid the problem all together.